# Single-variable approach to continuity of multivariable function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. A standard definition of continuity follows:
$$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists\delta>0: ||x-a||<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$$ where $||\cdot||$ is the Euclidean norm.

It is sometimes difficult to choose an appropriate $\delta$ while working with the norm. For example, consider the continuity at $a=(0,0)$ of $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by: $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2} & \text{$(x,y)\neq(0,0)$}\\
0 & \text{$(x,y)=(0,0)$}\end{cases}$$
At least to me, it is not obvious what $\delta$ to pick such that: $$||(x,y)||<\delta\Rightarrow\frac{x^3+y^3}{||(x,y)||^2}<\epsilon$$

Can we create a sufficient condition for the continuity of $f$ at $a$ by using a one-variable limit? I have in mind the following: $$\text{Define} \ F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R} \ \text{by} \ F(t)=f(tx,ty) \ \text{for all}\  ||(x,y)||\leq1$$
$$\text{Then}\ \forall\epsilon>0,\ \text{pick}\ \delta=\frac{\epsilon}{3}. |t|<\delta\Rightarrow \frac{t^3x^3+t^3y^3}{t^2x^2+t^2y^2}=t\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}\leq t(x^3+y^3)\leq 2t<\epsilon$$
So $F$ is continuous at $(0,0)$. Does this imply that $f$ is also continuous at $(0,0)$? I believe that it does, since we've shown that: $$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists O=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ ||(x,y)||<\delta\}: O \ \text{is open and} \ (x,y)\in O\Rightarrow f(x,y)<\epsilon $$

I hesitate, however, because continuity of multivariate functions is tricky and requires that $f(x)$ approaches $f(a)$ uniformly along all paths to $a$, which I'm not sure if the single-variable approach handles.

Comment: Be warned. There are functions that approach $0$ as you approach the origin along *every* curve $y=cx^n$ (all $c$, all $n>0$) and yet do not have a limit at the origin. This is a good technique for showing limits do *not* exist, but useless for showing that limits *do* exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confront with $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}1 &\text{if }y=x^2\land x\ne0\\ 0&\text{if } x=0\lor y\ne x^2\end{cases}$, for which $\lim_{t\to 0} f(tx,ty)=f(0,0)$ for all $x,y$, but it is discontinuous at $(0,0)$

**Added:**

An analogus conterexample which is $C^\infty$ on $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ and discontinuous at $(0,0)$ is $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x=0\lor y\le x^2\lor y\ge 3x^2\\ e^{x^{-4}}\exp\frac{1}{\left(y-x^2\right)(y-3x^2)}&\text{if }x\ne 0\land x^2<y<3x^2\end{cases}$$

In fact, $\lim_{t\to0}f(tx,ty)=f(0,0)=0$, but $\limsup_{(x,y)\to 0}f(x,y)\ge\limsup_{t\to 0} f(t,2t^2)=1$.

Comment: Thanks for the clear counterexample. Would it work with the modification that $F(t)=f(x+tu_1,y+tu_2)$ for some unit vector $u=(u_1,u_2)$?

Comment: @ruszfc What's the difference? Your original definition was just a stronger version of this (because there was $\forall$ instead of $\exists$), specialized to the case of continuity at $(x,y)=(0,0)$.